# How can i merge these two codes?

Tags: python

i have two pieces of code which actually work fine. The first piece of code requests historical data from oanda. It works fine and i can read and manipulate the data the way i want.

the second piece of code is the beginning of a portfolio optimisation tool which gets stock data from the google api. 
Since google does not deliver any forex data i wanted to merge the oanda code with the portfolio optimisation code.

After trying for hours i still did not get it done in the way that all data is requested in stored in columns correctly.

Since i am still a beginner i am here again asking you guys.

I would appreciate very much if you guys could help me with merging the code correctly. I would like to replace the symbols 'Close' data i receive from google by the 'openBid' data from oanda.

Thanks a lot in advance, you are doing a great job here!

have a nice day!

## first piece of code

```
import configparser  
import oandapy as opy  

oanda = opy.API(environment='practice',
                access_token='abc') 

import pandas as pd  
import time

data = oanda.get_history(instrument='EUR_USD', 
                         start='2016-10-01' ,  
                         end=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),  
                         granularity='D')  # minute bars  
df = pd.DataFrame(data['candles']) 

x = np.array(df['openBid'])
```

## second piece of code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

symbols =[   
"   AMZN"   ,
"   BABA"   ,
"   WMT "   ,
"   CMCSA"  ,
"   HD  "   
]
noa = len(symbols)

data = pd.DataFrame()
for sym in symbols:
    data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, 'google',  start ='2016-05-28', end='2017-05-28')['Close']
data.columns = symbols

print data

(data / data.ix[0]*100).plot(figsize=(8,5))

rets = np.log(data / data.shift(1))             # calculates log returns of the different securities
rets.mean() * 252                               # 252 trading days to annualize returns
rets.cov() * 252                                # covariance matrix of returns 

weights = np.random.random(noa)                 # generate five random numbers for the weights
weights /= np.sum(weights)                      # normalizes the the values so that the sum equals 1

np.sum(rets.mean() * weights) * 252             #Expected portfolio return

np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(rets.cov() * 252, weights)) #Expected portfolio variance 
np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(rets.cov() * 252, weights))) # Expected portfolio standarddeviation
```

Comment: have you tried using `pd.merge`?

Comment: i would like to replace the web.DataReader(sym, 'google',  start ='2016-05-28', end='2017-05-28')['Close'] by oanda.get_history(instrument='EUR_USD', 
                         start='2016-10-01' ,  
                         end=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),  
                         granularity='D')  # minute bars  
df = pd.DataFrame(data['candles']) and process further the 'openBid' data if you know what i mean